# How to know the root device size of some public AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Since I do not want to pay money for my testing, the free limit size is 10G.
I can know the root device root for some default AMI such as

```
Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03
The Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03 is an EBS-backed, PV-GRUB image. It includes Linux 3.2, AWS tools, and repository access to multiple versions of MySQL, PostgreSQL, Python, Ruby, and Tomcat.
Root Device Size: 8 GB
```

And the last row displayed 8GB.
However, if I find AMI in Community Page, it does not show the root device size.
Can anyone know how to use the instance such as centOS that is not provided by default but it is under 10GB so that I can still free use?

Comment: The current EBS volume limit in the AWS free tier is 30 GB. 
Don't look for AMIs on the community page. You have no idea who created them or how good they are.

Comment: because I want to try CentOS, but there is no CentOS in default page

Comment: Find a trusted source of CentOS AMIs and get the AMI id from them, not from the general pool of community AMIs where you don't know who created what. I would propose looking on the new AWS Marketplace, but oddly there is no generic CentOS being provided there: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace

Answer (score 7):

To determine the size each EBS volume associated with an AMI, use ec2-describe-images, with the image-id. Part of the output is the block device mapping, which includes the device, snapshot, and size in GB. For example, Amazon's Linux AMI (ami-e565ba8c), would result in the following:

```
ec2-describe-images ami-e565ba8c
IMAGE   ami-e565ba8c    amazon/amzn-ami-pv-2012.03.1.x86_64-ebs amazon  available       public          x86_64  machine aki-88aa75e1                    ebs    paravirtual      xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-dbb6e5a1   8
```

We can see that this AMI attached its root EBS volume (derived from snap-dbb6e5a1) to /dev/sda1 and that the size is 8GB.

Another example (a random CentOS AMI) - 6GB root device:

```
ec2-describe-images ami-d91dcbb0
IMAGE   ami-d91dcbb0    918714796546/CentOS-6.2-vs      918714796546    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-8e5ea7e7                    ebs    paravirtual      xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda                snap-14226d70   6
```

An example from my non-default region (my default region is us-east-1) - 10GB root device:

```
ec2-describe-images --region us-west-1 ami-2f9bc26a
IMAGE   ami-2f9bc26a    081293161529/CentOS-6.2-i386-virtastic-120215-3b       081293161529     available       public          i386    machine aki-87396bc2   ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda                snap-a4854dc6   10
```

Finally, if I take one of my own AMIs which has multiple attached EBS volumes (10GB, 5GB, 3GB), the output is:

```
ec2-describe-images  ami-xxxxxxxx
IMAGE   ami-xxxxxxxx    xxxxxxxxxx/MyAMIName   xxxxxxxxxx    available       private         x86_64    machine aki-407d9529                    ebs    paravirtual      xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-xxxxxxxa   10
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sdh1               snap-xxxxxxxb   5
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sdh2               snap-xxxxxxxc   3
```

The same command does let you apply filters to perform some basic searching on the AMIs. See the [AWS documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeImages.html) for the possible filters and their usage if you are interested.

To use ec2-describe-instances, you need to setup the API tools - they can be setup on either Windows or Linux and are command line tools. `--filter` is one of the parameters you pass the command, it allows you to narrow the search results by matching select criteria. Amazon details the installation of the API tools in [their documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html). Note that the API tools do not need to be setup on an instance - they can run from any computer.

For instance, to get all public, EBS backed, 64-bit images, that contain 'centos' in the name:

```
ec2-describe-images -a --filter "name=*centos*" --filter "is-public=true" --filter "root-device-type=ebs" --filter "architecture=x86_64"
```

To get all public, EBS backed, 64-bit images, that contain 'centos' in the name and that have an 8, 9, or 10GB EBS volume, you can use:

```
ec2-describe-images -a --filter "name=*centos*" --filter "is-public=true" --filter "root-device-type=ebs" --filter "architecture=x86_64" --filter "block-device-mapping.volume-size=8" --filter "block-device-mapping.volume-size=9" --filter "block-device-mapping.volume-size=10"

IMAGE   ami-10548979    021471307000/ebs-ami/hapx/centos_55_64bit       021471307000    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-3ad8b241   10
IMAGE   ami-c252f6ab    097336413681/centos-55-64-ebs-120513-2.6.35-8   097336413681    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-88aa75e1           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-ad4d0ed1   10
IMAGE   ami-f030c799    158864314994/mesos-hypertable-centos-4  158864314994   available        public          x86_64  machine                         ebs    paravirtual      xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-972d4bfd   10
IMAGE   ami-0c2bdc65    158864314994/mesos-hypertable-centos-6  158864314994   available        public          x86_64  machine                         ebs    paravirtual      xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-f31d7699   10
IMAGE   ami-cc887ea5    158864314994/mesos-hypertable-centos-7  158864314994   available        public          x86_64  machine                         ebs    paravirtual      xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-fb1a3091   10
IMAGE   ami-673af20e    180777447352/amazon-linux-centos-64-bit 180777447352   available        public          x86_64  machine aki-825ea7eb                   ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-8aac94e8   8
IMAGE   ami-6c47ba05    229012137537/centos-5.6-64bit-ebs-pvgrub        229012137537    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-427d952b           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-1f689b70   10
IMAGE   ami-3bec2e52    240054632121/centos-5.6-64-type-1       240054632121   available        public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da   ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-a2e4efc2   10
IMAGE   ami-26e1334f    276679183639/citrusleaf-2.0.23.54-trial-centos6 276679183639    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-4e7d9527           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda                snap-b8d619c3   8
IMAGE   ami-158a427c    324077455750/centos-5-x86_64-ebs-beta2.img      324077455750    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-427d952b           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-811153e3   10
IMAGE   ami-838a42ea    324077455750/centos-6-x86_64-ebs-beta2.img      324077455750    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-427d952b           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-0923616b   10
IMAGE   ami-d2855ebb    352560329280/harman-centos-5.6x64       352560329280   available        public          x86_64  machine aki-e5c1218c    ari-e3c1218a   ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-82a0dfff   10
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sdf                snap-7e9fe003   1
IMAGE   ami-18ba1e71    352560329280/harman-centos-5.6x64-pvc86 352560329280   available        public          x86_64  machine aki-e5c1218c    ari-e3c1218a   ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-db89e6a7   10
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sdf                snap-d189e6ad   1
IMAGE   ami-858741ec    405596411149/centos-5.6-x86_64-pegasus-cloud-tutorial-2405596411149     available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc   ari-b31cf9da             ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-cd3f5bac   10
IMAGE   ami-e2f8248b    499412572202/centos-5.8-base-with_selinux_disabled     499412572202     available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc   ari-b31cf9da             ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-06566b7d   10
IMAGE   ami-5469913d    658020488564/centoswithnxserver 658020488564    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-98a5e7f6   10
IMAGE   ami-48f90621    706600422991/centos_5_64_clean  706600422991    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-61c8560e   10
IMAGE   ami-d4de25bd    707215113857/centos5-x86_64-ebs 707215113857    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-f006f399    ari-f406f39d           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-e076448e   10
IMAGE   ami-fbd31292    752972755156/opencrowd-ideashare-centos-5.5-x64-trial-v01       752972755156    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-8ff2f4ee   10
IMAGE   ami-8f8d53e6    766915741798/nagiosxi/centos/6/2.2-SNAPSHOT-1/x86_64   766915741798     available       public          x86_64  machine aki-427d952b   ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-bb4f6bc1   10
IMAGE   ami-a90fd1c0    770727804447/Instance_import_demo_centos_5.6    770727804447    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-427d952b           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-c7a0a7bd   10
IMAGE   ami-d638cbbf    811118151095/suz-lab_ebs_centos-core-x86_64-5.5.7      811118151095     available       public          x86_64  machine                ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-30c0115c   10
IMAGE   ami-a038cbc9    811118151095/suz-lab_ebs_centos-core-x86_64-5.5.7-100g 811118151095     available       public          x86_64  machine                ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-b615c4da   10
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sdb1               snap-b015c4dc   100
IMAGE   ami-5a02fc33    811118151095/suz-lab_ebs_centos-core-x86_64-5.6.2      811118151095     available       public          x86_64  machine aki-f006f399   ari-f406f39d             ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-f18e929e   10
IMAGE   ami-bc649dd5    919814621061/app-apache64-centos55-1-20110609041807    919814621061     available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc   ari-b31cf9da             ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-58e05c36   10
IMAGE   ami-3f9e4856    919814621061/app64-centos5-us-east-1-20120117-20120117024004    919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-825ea7eb                    ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-8a7d1eee   10
IMAGE   ami-42ee362b    919814621061/app64-centos5-us-east-1-20120413-20120413071405    919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-825ea7eb                    ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-429e103f   10
IMAGE   ami-dbea33b2    919814621061/base64-centos5-us-east-1-20120405-20120405064803   919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-825ea7eb                    ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-3cb37441   10
IMAGE   ami-fbfe2992    919814621061/centos-5.7-scalr/centos/5/1.0-SNAPSHOT-1/x86_64    919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-825ea7eb                    ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-b649fbd2   10
IMAGE   ami-bb10c7d2    919814621061/centos-6-scalr/centos/6/1.0-SNAPSHOT-1/x86_64      919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-825ea7eb                    ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-62d85d06   10
IMAGE   ami-0166b168    919814621061/memcached64-centos5-us-east-1-20120116-20120116084405      919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machineaki-825ea7eb                     ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-92a1c4f6   10
IMAGE   ami-eaee3683    919814621061/memcached64-centos5-us-east-1-20120413-20120413073004      919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machineaki-825ea7eb                     ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-aaae20d7   10
IMAGE   ami-f920e690    919814621061/memcached64-centos55-us-east-1-20110802084407      919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-9f4a03fe   10
IMAGE   ami-0366b16a    919814621061/mongodb64-centos5-us-east-1-20120116-20120116084403        919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machineaki-825ea7eb                     ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-8aa1c4ee   10
IMAGE   ami-baee36d3    919814621061/mongodb64-centos5-us-east-1-20120413-20120413074803        919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machineaki-825ea7eb                     ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-58bb3525   10
IMAGE   ami-8d66b1e4    919814621061/mysql-app64-centos5-us-east-1-20120116-20120116085805      919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machineaki-825ea7eb                     ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-7eb4d11a   10
IMAGE   ami-5aee3633    919814621061/mysql-app64-centos5-us-east-1-20120413-20120413071404      919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machineaki-825ea7eb                     ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-de9f11a3   10
IMAGE   ami-8f66b1e6    919814621061/percona64-centos5-us-east-1-20120116-20120116085805        919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machineaki-825ea7eb                     ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-78b4d11c   10
IMAGE   ami-c4778ead    919814621061/percona64-centos55-1-20110608121605       919814621061     available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc   ari-b31cf9da             ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-bae252d4   10
IMAGE   ami-fc956e95    919814621061/percona64-centos55-10-20110627103005      919814621061     available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc   ari-b31cf9da             ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-3eae8d50   10
IMAGE   ami-313cfd58    919814621061/pgsql64-centos55-us-east1-20110816100807  919814621061     available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc   ari-b31cf9da             ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-6c06e90c   10
IMAGE   ami-0f66b166    919814621061/postgresql64-centos5-us-east-1-20120116-20120116084404     919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machineaki-825ea7eb                     ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-bca1c4d8   10
IMAGE   ami-e0ee3689    919814621061/postgresql64-centos5-us-east-1-20120413-20120413073205     919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machineaki-825ea7eb                     ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-24af2159   10
IMAGE   ami-0d66b164    919814621061/redis64-centos5-us-east-1-20120116-20120116084404  919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-825ea7eb                    ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-b6a1c4d2   10
IMAGE   ami-ecee3685    919814621061/redis64-centos5-us-east-1-20120413-20120413073004  919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-825ea7eb                    ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-7aaf2107   10
IMAGE   ami-83ed2eea    919814621061/redis64-centos55-us-east-1-20110906090406 919814621061     available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc   ari-b31cf9da             ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-4c61182c   10
IMAGE   ami-34a6565d    919814621061/scalr-centos55-x64 919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-bfc2b8d2   10
IMAGE   ami-bb0ac8d2    919814621061/scalr-centos55-x64-20110919        919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-ec5a468c   10
IMAGE   ami-2c9e6145    919814621061/scalr-centos56-x64 919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-5dda4f32   10
IMAGE   ami-c768abae    919814621061/scalr-centos60-x86_64-20110912     919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-4e7d9527           ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda                snap-e6defe86   8
IMAGE   ami-ec778385    919814621061/szr-app-apache-centos55-x86_64-ebs-1      919814621061     available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc   ari-b31cf9da             ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-156fb17f   10
IMAGE   ami-5afd1733    919814621061/szr-base-centos54-x86_64-ebs-1     919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-34c44d5f   10
IMAGE   ami-1402f77d    919814621061/szr-base-centos55-x86_64-ebs-1     919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-66b78d0d   10
IMAGE   ami-30ab5459    919814621061/szr-base-centos56-x86_64-ebs-1     919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-17ca4378   10
IMAGE   ami-30dd2a59    919814621061/szr-lamp-centos55-x86_64-ebs-1     919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-1921bd73   10
IMAGE   ami-fe0bff97    919814621061/szr-lb-nginx-centos55-x86_64-ebs-2 919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-854d92ef   10
IMAGE   ami-08f21861    919814621061/szr-mysql-centos54-x86_64-ebs-1    919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-16840d7d   10
IMAGE   ami-a002f7c9    919814621061/szr-mysql-centos55-x86_64-ebs-1    919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-f0a19b9b   10
IMAGE   ami-399e4850    919814621061/www64-centos5-us-east-1-20120117-20120117023604    919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-825ea7eb                    ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-847b18e0   10
IMAGE   ami-4eee3627    919814621061/www64-centos5-us-east-1-20120413-20120413071405    919814621061    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-825ea7eb                    ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-22810f5f   10
IMAGE   ami-df77b7b6    932221497473/centos_53_x86_64-(2/6/18)  932221497473   available        public          x86_64  machine                 windows ebs    hvm      xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-160d9876   11
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      xvdg            snap-180d9878   20
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      xvdh            snap-1a0d987a   10
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      xvdi            snap-1c0d987c   5
IMAGE   ami-6dd91a04    932221497473/centos_60_x86_64-(2/6/32)  932221497473   available        public          x86_64  machine aki-4e7d9527                   ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda                snap-66027306   8
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sdg                snap-68027308   10
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sdh                snap-6a02730a   20
IMAGE   ami-a847b9c1    932665800539/cloudopt-centos-5.6-x64-ebs        932665800539    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-b51cf9dc    ari-b31cf9da            ebs     paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1               snap-90a44afe   10
IMAGE   ami-dfc302b6    944964708905/rightimage_centos_6.0_x86_64_20110810.1_ebs944964708905    available       public          x86_64  machine aki-4e7d9527   ebs      paravirtual     xen
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda                snap-ede1da8c   8
```

Note, the above command will return AMIs that have multiple EBS volumes, if **any** of those volumes meet the criteria. You can always further filter your results using `grep`, should you desire.

As always, don't run AMIs from unknown sources. If you want a CentOS AMI, I would actually suggest sticking with Amazon's Linux. It is based on CentOS/RHEL (fully compatible with the binaries from EPEL), well maintained (packages are updated regularly, the current versions of many popular packages are available), is the officially supported AMI of EC2, and is very lightweight (comes with the bare minimum to start with - doesn't take too much space, uses little memory).

Comment: sorry, where can I filter the ec2-describe-images?? I can't find a place that can filter

Comment: Where can I type this command?

Comment: This is already legacy syntax

Answer (score 2):

Sloppy method to find details of all 8GB images

```
ec2-describe-images --all -v > ~/output.txt
cat ~/output.txt | grep -B 18 '<volumeSize>8</volumeSize>'
```

sample output in east region

```
          <imageId>ami-005daf69</imageId>
      <imageLocation>amazon/ElasticBeanstalk-Tomcat6-64bit-20110322-2041</imageLocation>
      <imageState>available</imageState>
      <imageOwnerId>102837901569</imageOwnerId>
      <isPublic>true</isPublic>
      <architecture>x86_64</architecture>
      <imageType>machine</imageType>
      <kernelId>aki-427d952b</kernelId>
      <imageOwnerAlias>amazon</imageOwnerAlias>
      <name>ElasticBeanstalk-Tomcat6-64bit-20110322-2041</name>
      <description>Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat 6 64-bit</description>
      <rootDeviceType>ebs</rootDeviceType>
      <rootDeviceName>/dev/sda1</rootDeviceName>
      <blockDeviceMapping>
        <item>
          <deviceName>/dev/sda1</deviceName>
          <ebs>
            <snapshotId>snap-4bd68427</snapshotId>
            <volumeSize>8</volumeSize>

    <item>
      <imageId>ami-00a97b69</imageId>
      <imageLocation>031458542082/TarCloud Client 0.1</imageLocation>
      <imageState>available</imageState>
      <imageOwnerId>031458542082</imageOwnerId>
      <isPublic>true</isPublic>
      <architecture>i386</architecture>
      <imageType>machine</imageType>
      <kernelId>aki-805ea7e9</kernelId>
      <name>TarCloud Client 0.1</name>
      <description>TarCloud Client 0.1</description>
      <rootDeviceType>ebs</rootDeviceType>
      <rootDeviceName>/dev/sda1</rootDeviceName>
      <blockDeviceMapping>
        <item>
          <deviceName>/dev/sda1</deviceName>
          <ebs>
            <snapshotId>snap-9a946ae1</snapshotId>
            <volumeSize>8</volumeSize>
```

Comment: You can get ec2-describe-images by downloading the EC2 API tools.

http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351

Comment: Can I use it in Windows? It seems so difficult to setup the EC2 API tools and the command is really hard if I just know little of Linux

Comment: it looks like there's a .NET version of the SDK and a Visual Studio toolkit, but it's a different ball of wax.  http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/  Sorry, I don't do windows.  The CLI unix method felt pretty easy to me.  It works on Mac OSX too.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the AWS tools. The official one is here:

http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351

If you install them as per the instructions you'll have a command line interface that will allow you to control the instance(s) from your local command line.